# env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory - Xcode bot CI

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-server, xcode-bots, xcode-server

I'm trying to setup CI pipeline for my project. I wrote a basic trigger for pre-integration as,

```
cd Project
pod install
```

But the integration fails with the below error,

```
env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory.
```

Answer (score -1):

**SOLUTION**

Run below command in terminal to refresh `executable-hooks`.

```
sudo gem install --user-install executable-hooks
```

then run

`pod install`